I want to add the Unity 2D Dissovle effect, but I'm having trouble
I'm trying to apply the Dissolve effect with the Unity Shader settings, but I'm not getting it applied on the last Combine side, and because of that I can't see it being applied in the scene.
I've searched both Google and YouTube, but I don't know the exact error and I'm not sure what to look for, so I'm asking this question. And importantly, you're working in 2D
enter image description here
(I ran it through a translator, so the grammar may be weird).

We've fixed that related issue.
